# Snorkeling, Spear fishing, skin diving - Same tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see we have a scuba diving and a snorkeling tag. 
Do we group free diving / apnea diving under snorkeling, or do we create its own tag? 
What about spear fishing? Does it fall under free diving or a tag on its own? 
Is competitive spearfishing & competitive Apnea diving on topic?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to create a tag is to put it on a question, and a tag not on any question will be deleted in about 24 hours. So when a free diving, apnea diving, or spear fishing question comes along, it should be tagged with the relevant tag, but we don't need to (and can't) do anything before then.

I do think competitive spearfishing and apnea diving are fine.

Comment: Sorry maybe i shoudl clarify, the question was more about whether these are part of snorkeling tag so do we include description on snorkeling tag for now to include free diving, etc and then if later we get free diving tags we then update tag description.

Comment: We could do it that way Alex - but it doesn't really matter at this stage. Tags are an aid to searching - they are helpful but on a site like this, not essential yet. On a huge site like SO they are, as you filter the questions you see by the tags you are interested in - but we are a long way off being that big

Answer (score 3):

Generally tags are created if questions need them, rather than creating a tag to then populate with questions.

So if we end up having a few freediving questions it would make sense to have that tag, but let's not create tags unnecessarily.

Comment: But do we need a free diving tag or do we just include it as part of snorkeling?

Comment: We don't **need** any tags. It makes sense if we get enough questions that require the distinction between the two types of diving. (I know - very subjective isn't it :-)

Comment: I'd say they overlap but there maybe times where it's rather more specific to one or the other? Just my reasoning is that snorkeling is much more casual than free diving?